# Coldfusion, Compare two TimeStamp to get the difference in Hours

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, diff, datediff

I'm going have SELECT a TIMESTAMP from the MySQL database. What I want to do is compare that to the current time using ColdFusion.

If 1+ from the DIFF do this....
If LT 1hr do this....

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [DateDiff()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd1.html) in ColdFusion

```
DateDiff("h", yourQuery.date, now())
```